# create ether wallet using nodejs

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, ethereum-classic

I have implemented the code which is creating new wallet but I am not able to get the private key of that wallet. Can anyone tell me like what is the proper way in which I can create new wallet which can provide me the private key as well using node.

my code:-

```
web3.personal.newAccount(name, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            next(err,null);
        } else {
            next(null , res);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//generate private key    
privateKey = web3.eth.accounts.create().privateKey.substr(2)

//generates pubKey from privateKey, encrypts it and store in keystore folder.
web3.eth.personal.importRawKey(privateKey, pin)
    .then((result) => {

    //store pub address.
    publicAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(result)
})
```

Sort of a similar question was also posted here:
[How to generate Ethereum wallets & keys on serverside with JS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/52338/41248)

Answer (score 0):

First get a INFURA NODE URL by signing up and creating a project on https://infura.io/

I did it using the following code

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
var web3provider = "https://INFURA_URL";
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(web3provider));
var account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
console.log(account);
```

You will get the public and the private key and a new account will be created.