# How to generate Ethereum wallets & keys on serverside with JS?

Tags: nodes, server-side

Anybody knows, how can ether wallets be generated on serverside (node.js). It's needed for service, to create a new wallets for new customers. Maybe something like [bitcoinJS-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) but for ethereum? But can't find with my own, please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using web3js library, here is how you do it on nodejs serverside

```
//generate private key    
privateKey = web3.eth.accounts.create().privateKey.substr(2)

//generates pubKey from privateKey, encrypts it and store in keystore folder.
web3.eth.personal.importRawKey(privateKey, pin)
    .then((result) => {

    //store pub address.
    publicAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(result)
})
```

...

There you go.

Comment: What's "pin" here?

Comment: @Ruham it's a string you wish to encrypt with the privateKey that was generated and store in keystore directory.