# how do I create an ethereum valid key pair in nodeJS?

Tags: private-key, public-key

I need to generate a key pair that can be used to write the a besu (ethereum) private ledger.   I wrote the following code but the architect says this will probably not work with ethereum.

The [examples](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52338/how-to-generate-ethereum-wallets-keys-on-serverside-with-js) he gave me do not compile with the latest packages, [seems overly complex](https://link.medium.com/Y6UVKhYlx1), or [make no sense to me](https://github.com/bokub/vanity-eth/blob/master/src/js/vanity.js) in that they don't do anything different from my simple code.

Here's my code:

```
import * as keypair from 'keypair';
import * as forge from 'node-forge';
const pair = keypair();
const publicKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(pair.public);
const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(pair.private);
```

Not making excuses, I don't know where to begin or what to even search on.   What do I need to generate to have acceptable keys for use with ethereum?

Comment: why are you not using `web3.utils` package from `web3js` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const util = require("ethereumjs-util");

const privateKey = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
const publicKey = "0x" + util.privateToPublic(privateKey).toString("hex");
```